# How to change AUCTeX latex compile command? (using Emacs 23)

Tags: pdftex, emacs, auctex

I'd like to configure AUCTeX to compile without stopping on errors. I can do it from a terminal with

```
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode filename.tex
```

but AUCTeX apparently does

```
pdflatex filename.tex
```

when asked to compile with C-c C-c. How can I force the "-interaction=nonstopmode" option?

Comment: Can you do it through `M-x customize-group RET TeX-command`?

Comment: Changing the 'TeX Command' and 'LaTeX Command' variables suppresses the display of errors, but compilation still halts on the first error, which is different from the command-line behavior.

Comment: You may want to [use latexmk](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8026921/789593) to handle compiling. Then you can set the flags via .latexmkrc

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I use Emacs 23.4 on Mac OS 10.7. That's what I've done:

- Create a LaTeX file so you have all the AUCTeX menus available
- Go to LaTeX -> Customize AUCTeX -> Browse options
- Click on TeX Command
- Expand TeX Command List and press on one INS button
- Fill the appeared fields as here:

  1. Name: LaTeXnonint
  2. Command: %`%l -interaction=nonstopmode %(mode)%' %t
  3. How: TeX-run-command

In this way, if I try to compile (hitting C-c C-c LaTeXnonint) a file like:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
\latex
\end{document}
```

I get no interaction on the present error (`\latex` instead of `\LaTeX`)

P.S. the first three points of the list can be made using the shortcut showed by @Seamus

Comment: Is there a way to make this change in emacs init file ?

Answer (score 1):

Add this in you .emacs file:

```
(setf (nth 1 (assoc "LaTeX" TeX-command-list))
      "%`%l -interaction=nonstopmode %(mode)%' %t")
```